# Django url keeps duplicating(Dynamic Navigation)

Tags: python, django, permalinks

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    ....
    slug = models.SlugField(help_text = "You do not need to change this unless you want to change the url")

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "Entries"

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    cat = slugify(self.category)    
    return "%s/%s/"  % (cat,self.slug)
```

## views

```
def index(request):
    all_entries = Entry.objects.filter(status=1)
    treatments = all_entries.filter(category='treatments')
    female = all_entries.filter(category='female')
    male = all_entries.filter(category='male')
    work = all_entries.filter(category='work')

    return render_to_response('index.html',locals())

def entry_page(request,slug_add):
    all_entries = Entry.objects.filter(status=1)
    page = all_entries.get(slug=slug_add)

    treatments = all_entries.filter(category='treatments')
    female = all_entries.filter(category='female')
    male = all_entries.filter(category='male')
    work = all_entries.filter(category='work')
    return render_to_response('index.html',locals())
```

## url

```
 url(r'^$','hypno_pages.views.index'),
 url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
 url(r'^$','hypno_pages.views.index'),   
 url(r'^(treatments|male|female|work)/(?P<slug_add>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$','hypno_pages.views.entry_page'),
```

## template

```
<div class="subnav ui-corner-all">
  <h3>xxxxx can help to treat any of the following conditions </h3>
<ul class = 'float' >       
         {% for line in treatments|slice:":5" %} 
        <li ><a href='{{line.get_absolute_url}}'>{{ line.title }}</a></li>
     {% empty %}

         {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <ul class = 'float'>
     {% for line in treatments|slice:"5:10" %}
        <li ><a href="{{line.get_absolute_url }}" >{{ line.title }}</a></li>
     {% empty %}
     {% endfor %}
</ul>
  .......
```

*edit*That is the template code,just truncated it,other parts are just repeated.

My issue.I have a main index page with a navigation bar that has a dropdown box with lots of links(which will be added dynamically from the database  once the client adds something,Now my problem is that on the navigation link say I click on a link 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/treatments/what-to-do/' I go to a the linked page but now all the links in the navigation bar change to 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/treatments/what-to-do/treatments/what-to-do/' accrording to the particular link.
   I am 1 week with Django and a month with python maybe am just missing something.
thanks

Comment: So, which code is causing your problem, do you think?

Comment: @ephan - I suggest you post the portion of your template code which shows those links being generated.

Comment: @DominicRodger I have just put up the template code.

Comment: @Marcin That is what am trying to figure out.My research right now is leading me towards template_context_processors as a solution.

Comment: No offense, but if you're doing work for a client, perhaps you *shouldn't* use something you only have 1 week of experience with. If you're familiar with something else already, like PHP, use that for your client now and learn Django in your free time. Personally, I'd be pissed if I was your client and knew this.

Comment: @ChrisPratt ,I know this is old,but like you said,I had already made the site in php codeigniter and was ready to deliver,In my free time I decided to learn django by remaking the site in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it looks like you should use absolute pathing in your "a hrefs", since like you use it, the link is relative and will be appended to the (url-)path your are already on,

try `<a href="/{{line.get_absolute_url }}" >` instead.

Also I would use the `@pemarlink` decorator for your `get_absolute_url` function. Have a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#the-permalink-decorator).

Comment: thanks alot,tried that,didn't help and I have been fighting with permalink for a few days now,the url always shows blank.I know most of my issues are basic,still learning.For now am gonna use django-context-processors for this problem.